# Find an existing route from url string

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a promo block, that contains several images and links. Some of them are leading to my site, some to external resources. Currently, i use this piece of code for this links.

```
<a {{ bindAttr href="link" }}><img {{ bindAttr src="image" }} /></a>
```

However, this actually reloads a page, and i don't want that in case i'm navigating inside my site. Also, it could mean breaking my app if we encounter some non-existent routes, in case of typos or whatever.
So, what i'm trying to do is to add an action, that checks if the route exists and then do a proper `transitionTo`, and if the route doesn't exist do some sort of default fallback, but i don't know how to make this check. Have anyone did something similar already?

P.S. I know that `transitionTo` could accept urls as a parameter, but Ember docs say

```
It is also possible to pass a URL (a string that starts with a /). 
This is intended for testing and debugging purposes 
and should rarely be used in production code.
```

And doesn't help with preventing transition if the route doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a default route that would be a 'catch-all' which you would specify in your router as something like:

```
this.route('badRoute', {path: '/*pathname' });
```

at the bottom after you have declared all your routes. When none of your routes match, this will be matched and you can redirect or whatever when it transitions to that route.

Comment: And i guess i should `transitionTo` with plain url?

Comment: so you will have an App.badRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({ and in it, you can have a redirect hook which will accept a valid ember route.

Comment: Nah, i meant, original problem. Making action and doing `transitionTo` through my link